# How can I getRange by index row and column from sheet openByID?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using vscode to edit code faster and when I pushed the code up I used the function openbyID or openbyURL as follows:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('12cuf3BUNwDiqehXoxXSCPAQb6lQFuBjml7uKq5T2Zy8');
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
```

However after using the code. I was unable to use this function

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, 1, numRows);
```

What should I do in this case? I want to use the getrange function with four arguments instead of strings.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the sheet itself, not just the spreadsheet (workbook).

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<ID>').getActiveSheet()
```

Now sheet ranges will be accessible on the sheet variable.

As for passing arguments, getRange doesn't care as long as the results are integers or A1Notation.

Comment: Hi blrzzzt, that was the big flaw, I corrected it and it worked.
thank you very much.